# PaymentRelayActivity error in stripe android

Tags: android

I am implementing stripe in my project,I'm able to do transactions successfully i can see in my dashboard,but in my project iam getting error
Unable to find explicit activity class

{com.zinggr.customer/com.stripe.android.view.PaymentRelayActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I checked my manifest.xml file with some suggessions  having fully qualified path in activity delcaration

The same code i tried with creating new project i can see my success transaction call back also

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution for this ,I have facebook integration in my project,So i userd merge=include property in manifest file.Instead fo merge=include ,i replaced with merge=replace .So then It started working